# Public folder in an encrypted home directory?

Tags: ecryptfs

I have encrypted home directory, which has `drwx------` permissions after mounting.

Is there a possibility to have `Public` directory inside it which is accessible by other users?

As I understand, it's not possible to have such directory inside `$HOME` without changing the parent directory permissions as well.

I guess the way is to create the folder in some other place (e.g. `/home/shared/`), make me the owner, give the appropriate permissions to other users and create a symlink from my home directory to it?

Comment: "without changing the parent directory" or create a dir in a dir in home(?)

Comment: I mean without changing permissions of the home directory.

Comment: Symlink sounds like the most appropriate solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed the public directory so that Nginx could access files in my project directories. This solution came to me today:

```
sudo chmod 750 /home/vic
sudo adduser www-data vic
```

So I gave `r-x` access to my home directory to the user group to which my user belongs to. Then I added Nginx user to my group.